# How to use Android's Looper in a drawing thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview

I'm trying to make a simple airplane game to build my skills and have some fun. But I've hit a roadblock with `Thread`s, `Looper`s, and message queues when trying to pass a message from an `onTouch` event of a `TextView` to the `Thread` drawing my airplanes. I'm going to try to include only the essential bits of code below  and use "..." to indicate omitted lines.

I'm drawing in a separate, good old-fashioned android thread. Here's the constructor of the `Thread`:

```
public class BenThread extends Thread {
...
public BenThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context,
        BenSurfaceView surfaceView) {
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.context = context;
    this.surfaceView = surfaceView;
    this.isRunning = false;

    Bitmap planeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.getResources(), R.drawable.fighters);
    airplane = new Airplane(50, 50, 2, 0, planeImage);
}
```

Before I show the run method, note that there's a `SurfaceView` that creates and starts the `Thread` when the `SurfaceChanged()` is called. In the `onCreate()` of my main `Activity`, I create a final instance of my custom `SurfaceView`:

```
final BenSurfaceView surfaceView = (BenSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
```

In the UI layout, there a `TextView` sitting at bottom center with an `OnTouchListener` hooked up. In `onTouch()`, for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, the following line is called:

```
surfaceView.thread.handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```

Back to the thread class, the handler for this empty message is created in the run method, along with the `Looper` creation:

```
public void run() {
    super.run();
    Looper.prepare(); // Creates a Message Queue for the thread
    MessageQueue queue = Looper.myQueue();
    queue.addIdleHandler(new IdleHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean queueIdle() {
            Looper.myLooper().quit();
            return false;
        }
    });
    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.i("HANDLING", "SOMETHING");
        }
    };
    Looper.loop();

    while (isRunning) {
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // spin in a while loop for a while
        while ((currentTime - previousTime) < REFRESH_RATE) {
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        airplane.move();
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas != null) {
            surfaceView.draw(canvas);
            airplane.draw(canvas);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I run as is, I get a nice little animation of airplanes moving across the screen.
[image]
But, when I click the `Button` at the bottom, I see from the log that I sent a message to a dead thread. Well, I guess I killed it in the `IdleHandler`. So now let me comment out the quit method:

```
// Looper.myLooper().quit();
```

Now my app looks considerably less exciting:
[image]

But, when I click the `Button` at the bottom and look at the log, there is proof that my message has been handled! So the big question is, how can I run the message loop and still see my animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you call `Looper.loop()`, it should not return until the thread is ready to stop.  Having your game loop *after* the `Looper.loop()` call doesn't make sense.  At that point the thread is "dead" in the sense that the Looper is no longer listening for messages.

If you want your thread to run in `while (isRunning)`, do that.  If you want it to be message-driven, do that.  Don't try to do both in the same thread.  (And please don't spin on the CPU -- eats up battery quickly on a mobile device.)

You can find some notes about game loops, and about SurfaceView and threading, in appendices A and B of [this article](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).  There are various examples of animated rendering using Handler in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  For example, the "record GL app" activity uses Choreographer to send a message to the render thread whenever it's time to draw.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do the reading. Would you mind explaining the concept of "spinning on the CPU"?

Comment: Your `while ((currentTime - previousTime) < REFRESH_RATE)` loop will execute continuously until the desired time is reached.  If you turn this into a `Thread.sleep()` call, the thread will be idle until it's time to wake up.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the IdleHandler(). It is executed immediately quitting you looper. I commented your code:

```
public void run() {
super.run();
Looper.prepare();
MessageQueue queue = Looper.myQueue();
queue.addIdleHandler(new IdleHandler() {
    // This is executed immediately when the looper is idle.
    // So this looper is quitted
    // and thread starts to execute "while" loop
    @Override
    public boolean queueIdle() {
        Looper.myLooper().quit();
        return false;
    }
});
handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.i("HANDLING", "SOMETHING");
    }
};
Looper.loop();  // Take into account that this function is blocking
// This "while" loop is executed after the looper is quitted from IdleHandler
// So why your game is running
// When you click your button it tries to send message to quitted looper
// and you get the corresponding error message
while (isRunning) {
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // spin in a while loop for a while
    while ((currentTime - previousTime) < REFRESH_RATE) {
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    airplane.move();
    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    if (canvas != null) {
        surfaceView.draw(canvas);
        airplane.draw(canvas);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

}

When you commented the IdleHandler the thread executes Looper.loop() (it is blocking) method so the while loop is not being reached.

Answer (score 0):

After the clarification from @fadden and @armansimonyah13, I dropped the misguided attempt to send messages between threads. In the main Activity, rather than sending a message to the thread like so:

```
surfaceView.thread.handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```

and trying to handle it in the thread, I simply update public data in the thread (from within the TextView's onTouch handler):

```
surfaceView.thread.airplane.setVelocity(8);
```

Now when you click the TextView at the bottom, the planes speed up. That's the kind of UI-thread to rendering-thread interactivity I was going for.

By the way, now the run loop looks like:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    while (isRunning) {
        airplane.move();
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas != null) {
            surfaceView.draw(canvas);
            airplane.draw(canvas);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```